# shrink pdf slightly, add text, save

Tags: c#, pdf, flatten, pdfsharp

I want to open an existing pdf, shrink it slighty so theres new white space at the bottom and add a a string of text to said white space.

I took from the pdfsharp samples combining pdfs and method1 works great for most of my pdfs when they are simple scanned in pdfs.

When the pdf contains acroforms though the pdf is saved with no acroforms visible, all text is lost. Ximage and xgraphics doesnt pick up the acroforms. i tried flattening the file and saving beforehand but it will make the fields read only but fields are still lost upon save.
method 2 keeps the acroforms but I cannot alter the scaling of the page.

Do not want to use itext or other liscenced options, but dont have to use pdfsharp if there's another option available

Method1:

```
PPdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();            
XGraphics gfx; 

// get existing pdf   
XPdfForm form1 = XPdfForm.FromFile(filename1);            
PdfPage page1 = outputDocument.AddPage();

// Get a graphics object for page1          
gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page1);
double ratio = form1.PointWidth / form1.PointHeight;
double desiredWidth = ratio * (form1.PointHeight - 31);
//draw existing pdf on new pdf but leave space at bottom
gfx.DrawImage(form1, new XRect(0, 0, desiredWidth, form1.PointHeight-31));

//Draw text at bottom
XFont font1 = new XFont("Verdana", 12, XFontStyle.Bold);                          
gfx.DrawString(stringHere, font1, XBrushes.Black,new XRect(0,0,page1.Width, page1.Height - 18), XStringFormats.BottomCenter);                           
gfx.Dispose();
```

Method2

```
//import existing pdf
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDocument1 = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(filename1, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage firstPage = inputDocument1.Pages[0];
//add the existing pdf to page but it's not shrunk
outputDocument.AddPage(firstPage);
'''
```

Comment: I found FreeSpire.PDF that has a flatten method that works

Comment: Feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with a working solution for people with the same question.